# UIViewController interfaceOrientation problem

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a Subclass of UIViewController as usual. When I load the App, I need to size some elements that I have to put in programmatically. Of course, the size depends on the interface orientation: So, I did:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  switch( [self interfaceOrientation] ) {
     case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
     case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
          NSLog(@"Portrait");
          break:
     case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
     case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
          NSLog(@"Landscape");
          break;
  }
```

But no matter of the orientation of the simulator/device, the case is always Portrait in viewDidLoad/WillAppear, even if everything rotate correctly.
In the Plist I've added all supported orientations.
Hints?

Comment: Hitting exactly the same problem! This has always been an issue in the simulator.
The best is: break in "willRotate" and it tells you it will rotate to landscape. Next it breaks in layoutSubview. If you check the orientation there, it is portrait! WTF?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you should override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and return `YES` there ?? If you did, move your code to that method.

Answer (score 8):

Try `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` and check for `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`, `UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` etc in  your switch as `[self interfaceOrientation]` is unreliable in my experience.

Comment: I've never tried with the statusBarOrientation. The device's one is unuseful since the moment that it tells you if you lay the iPad on a table.

Comment: The status bar tip saved my day. UISplitViewController always returns prortrait.

Comment: statusBarOrientation returns a UIInterfaceOrientation (not UIDeviceOrientation) so you should use UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait(), otherwise, you occasionally get weird results.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that interface orientation in willAppear returns incorrect interface orientation.
2) try to look here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

3) Make sure that main view controller is only viewcontroller in window (there is only one vc in window)

Answer (score 0):

I was working with the rotations and orientations of the iOS App. I found that self.interfaceOrientation will always give you a correct result if called in viewDidAppear or after that.

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation should be preferred when adding a view directly to UIWindow.

Hope it helps.